# Центрирование резинового блока

Tags: html, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие бывают способы центрирования резинового блока, я нашел только один, а именно:

html

```
<div id="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
</div>
```

css

```
body, html { text-align: center; }

div {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 450px;
 max-width: 1200px; 
 height: 80px; padding: 10px;
 background: #ffffa2; 
 border: 1px solid red;
 text-align: left;
 }
```

Ширина блока должна иметь прямую зависимость от содержимого (хотя в примере выше, это не совсем так).

Google и Yandex, вразумительных вариантов не дали...

Answer (score 1):

Иногда помогают всякие:

```
1. left:50%; right:50%;
2. padding-left:50%; padding-right:50%;
3. margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;
```

или

```
var w = document.getElementById('box').width;
var raz = document.clientWidth //Или используйте свой способ
document.getElementById('box').style.left = raz / 2;

p.s. У box должен быть position:absolute
```

Comment: Нет, это не то.

Comment: @Alex83 А что для вас то?

Comment: @danpetruk. Такие варианты отлично работают со статикой, но не с резиной. Если Вы знаете как сие действо оформить с резиной, то будьте добры конкретный пример.

С Уважением, Александр

Comment: @danpetruk, c помощью javascript, сделать сие не составит особого труда. А меня интересуют варианты на чистом CSS.

Comment: @Alex83 вы можете написать в вопрос ВСЁ что хотите. 

Если без js, используйте css -кин calc. Кроссплатформености никакой, зато сам факт будет радовать

Comment: @danpetruk, дело в том, что это не для конкретного рабочего проекта, а скорее для общего развития.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, который я чаще всего использую. Работает везде. Основное правило margin: 0px auto;

```
body, html { text-align: center; }

div {
 min-width: 450px;
 max-width: 1200px; 
 height: 80px; padding: 10px;
 background: #ffffa2; 
 border: 1px solid red;
 text-align: left;
margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

Comment: Уважаемый @zhenyab, прочитайте внимательно вопрос. Вы дали тот же пример, который описан в вопросе, за исключением того, что ширина блока, в Вашем случае пляшет не от содержимого. А нужно, чтобы ширина блока имела прямую зависимость от содержимого. В общем, нужна чистая резина без указания размеров блока.

Comment: Да, действительно я не понял. Если не указывать размеров, то тогда DIV автоматически растянется на всю ширину отеческого объекта, а тогда о каком центрировании идет речь?
Поконкретнее опишите задачу. Может кусок дизайна покажете, как вы хотите чтобы оно было, чтобы не на пальцах объяснять?

Comment: @zhenyab, попытаюсь объяснить еще раз. Допустим, родитель - это body.
В нем есть резиновый блок (ширина которого зависит от содержимого). Вот именно этот блок и необходимо расположить четко по центру родителя (в нашем случае, родителем выступает body).

Comment: О, если объянсять медленно - я понимаю быстрее :)). Но боюсь одними силами CSS с такой проблемой не справиться.

Comment: @zhenyab, если интересно, то я нашел еще один вариант, а именно:

Если div'y указать display: table и margin: 0 auto, то желаемый результат будет получен.

Удачи